# Joining to perform a comparison match with possible swapped data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I'm trying to do a comparison match in `snowflake` between the `first_name`, `middle_name`, and `last_name` from a target table (700K rows) and from source table (1.5M rows). The values in the `first_name`, `middle_name`, and `last_name` can be partially, or fully swapped in the `source` table, that is the value in the `first_name` can be swapped with the value in the `last_name` or any other way. For a positive probable identification at least two matches need to be correct. I then do further processing to guarantee the accuracy of the match.

**Example:**

*case 1*: first name (target) = first name (source) |  middle name (target) = middle name. (MATCH)

*case 2*: first name (target) = last name (source) | middle name (target) = middle name (source) | last name (target) = first name (source) -> first name swapped with last lame (MATCH)

**Example (with table)**:

```
Target Table
id   | first_na_t    |   middle_name_t   |     last_name_t
1    |   ffa         |       mma         |         lla    
2    |   ffa         |       mmb         |         lla
3    |   ffb         |       ffa         |         llb
4    |   ffc         |       mmd         |         lla
...

Source Table
id      | first_name_s  |   middle_name_s |     last_name_s
1       |   lla         |       mmb         |         ffa    
5       |   ffa         |       mmb         |         lla
3       |   ffb         |       ffa         |         llb
4       |   mmd         |       ffc         |         lla
...
```

From the example tables the attempt that I used was to compare the first row in the `target` table with all the other rows in the `source` table using a `CROSS JOIN` with a `CASE` afterwards but this is proving to be inefficient and slow.

Is there any way to `JOIN` this cleverly where you would compare the rows in the `target` table against the rows in the `source` table and come out with at least 2 match even though any of the `name` columns could be swapped. Also I **can not** use the `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

You can express the logic like this:

```
from TARGET_TABLE T join
     SOURCE_TABLE S
     on ((case when s.FIRST_NAME_s in (t.FIRST_NAME_T, t.MIDDLE_NAME_T, t.LAST_NAME_T then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when s.MIDDLE_NAME_s in (t.FIRST_NAME_T, t.MIDDLE_NAME_T, t.LAST_NAME_T then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when s.LAST_NAME_s in (t.FIRST_NAME_T, t.MIDDLE_NAME_T, t.LAST_NAME_T then 1 else 0 end)
        ) >= 2
```

However, that might take forever to run.

Instead, let's break the names into separate rows and aggregate:

```
select t.id, s.id
from (target_table t cross join lateral
      (values (t.first_name_t), (t.middle_name_t), (t.last_name_t)
      ) vt(name)
     ) join
     (source_table t cross join lateral
      (values (s.first_name_s), (s.middle_name_s), (s.last_name_s)
      ) vs(name)
     )
     on vt.name = vs.name
group by t.id, s.id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Note:  This might get into a bit of confusion if different name components are the same within a name, but you can tweak the logic to handle that if necessary.

Comment: is the second query written for `postgress` because I keep getting errors when I try to run fit in `snowflake`?

Comment: @Lukasz . . . Perhaps Snowflake requires a comma instead of the `cross join`.